# Graph Theory - Minimization by degree problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm a 3rd year Math undergrad and I decided to take an algorithms extra class. This question was a bonus one on my mid-term and I still have no idea on how to approach it.

> Given $n$ vertices, each labeled with a number from $[1...n]$ and $m$
>   distinct pairs of those labels, you are allowed to place a **directed** edge between the two nodes of any such pair.
>
> Devise an efficient procedure to determine the minimum number of nodes left with **in** degree equal to $0$, after an optimal choice of edges is done. Here, an optimal choice is made in such a way that as many nodes as possible have  **in** degree greater than $0$.
>
> Hint : Is constructing the graph absolutely necessary ?

Example :

$m=n=5$
and the pair set $p=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(5,2),(5,3)\}$

One possible solution :

[image]

To me, this question seems like it doesn't really have anything to do with graphs, it strikes me more as a dynamic programming trick question. Maybe there are some theorems or results that I'm not aware of that could help here.

Answer (score 1):

The $m$ unordered pairs you're given to begin with can be thought of as an *undirected* graph. Clearly the solution can be found separately for each connected component of the graph, so assume without loss of generality that we have just an $m$-edge *connected* graph on $n$ nodes.

Now if the graph is a tree (that is, if $m=n-1$), then there needs to be a node with in-degree $0$; there are not enough edges to point towards all of the nodes. But we'll never need to leave *more* than one node without in-pointing edges. Just select an arbitrary node to be the unlucky one. Since the graph is a tree, each edge can be given a well-defined direction *away* from the unlucky node, and this will hit every node that is not our chosen root.

If the graph is *not* a tree, then we can always do even better and leave *no* nodes with in-degree $0$. Simply select a spanning tree. By assumption that is an edge that is not part of the spanning tree; choose an arbitrary direction for that, and declare its target to be the *root* of the spanning tree. Then, as before, hit every non-root node with an edge away-from-the-root in the spanning tree. Finally give the edges not yet processed arbitrary directions.

What this adds up to is that the number we're being asked for is simply

> The number of connected components in the original graph where the connected component contains fewer edges than nodes.

This can be computed by a simple depth- or breadth-first scan through the graph to identify connected components and count their sizes (edges and nodes) while doing so.

(Incidentally, you can easily extend this algorithm to actually produce a winning direction assignment in linear time, since a DFS or BFS implicitly constructs a spanning tree as part of its operation. But the question doesn't ask for this extension; it just wants the count).